# Cassandra comes up with UnavailableException

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

I'm using Datastax driver for Cassandra on C#.
My cluster has 2 servers (each of them is a data-center). When I declare the KEYSPACE as follow:

`CREATE KEYSPACE exc WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' : 2, 'DC2' : 2 }`

After that, whether I perform SELECT/INSERT operation, I get this:

`cassandra.UnavailableException: Not enough replica available for query at consistency One (1 required but only 0 alive)`

I've used the nodetool to check my cluster and found that the nodes are good and no balance
problems are seen.

So has anyone come up with similar problem ? What do I have to do to make it work ?
Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272675/getting-unable-to-complete-request-one-or-more-nodes-were-unavailable-when-pe

Comment: Yes thx. But after I try `CREATE KEYSPACE exc WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' : 1, 'DC2' : 1 }`, the problem is still the same. My 2 servers both may insert data to Cassandra, should I just make it one DC ?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier marking the duplicate, Your datacenter is named datacenter1. Your Keyspace is looking for DC1 (and dc2) which do not exist.

Comment: Please read the answer to the linked dupe for more detailed info

Comment: OH, I'm sorry to make so stupid mistake. And thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use nodetool ring or nodetool status to see if there are any nodes marked as being down.

Comment: `Datacenter: datacenter1
========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address          Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID
     Rack
UN  192.253.224.106  2.6 MB     256     47.3%  f94a4f5f-154c-41d7-9d97-5494e189c
8d1  rack1
UN  112.213.119.135  2.28 MB    256     52.7%  4e6465fc-960e-4e9c-8805-39af127ff
152  rack1`

Comment: Here is my `nodetool status` result. I've seen the two tokens are the same and I don't whether this matters or not.